# A direct proof that minimal primes are associated

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

It is a well-known theorem that, for a Noetherian ring $A$, the minimal primes of $A$ are among the associated primes of $A$; i.e., for every minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, there is an element $f \in A$ such that $\operatorname{Ann}(f) = \mathfrak{p}$. Morally, one might think of $f$ as a "characteristic function" of the irreducible component Spec $A/\mathfrak{p}$ of Spec $A$.

The usual proof of this fact is to look at the set of associated primes of $A$ (or more generally of an $A$-module), together with one or more other sets of primes of $A$, and then go on proving various things that finally conclude with "these collections of primes have the same minimal elements." I find this proof not particularly satisfactory.  What I would like is a proof that starts off "Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a minimal prime of $A$" and then proceeds to "construct" an element $f \in A$ such that $\operatorname{Ann}(f) = \mathfrak{p}$.  Unfortunately, I have not had much success with proceeding along these lines. Is there anyone who knows (or is able to invent) such a proof?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to assume that $0$ has a primary decomposition, then take one which is minimal say $0 = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n Q_i$ with radicals $P_i = \sqrt{Q_i}$. Now the minimal primes are the $P_i$.

Let me show that $P = P_1$ is associated. Let $R = \bigcap_{i = 2}^n Q_i$, $Q = Q_1$. So $0 = Q \cap R$, and

$$R = \frac{R}{Q \cap R} \cong \frac{R + Q}{Q} \subset \frac{A}{Q}.$$

So $\mathop{Ass}(R) \subset \mathop{Ass}(A/Q) = \{ P \}$, where the last equality uses the assumption that $A$ is noetherian. Again, since $A$ is Noetherian, $\mathop{Ass}(R) \neq \emptyset$, so $P \in \mathop{Ass}(R) \subset \mathop{Ass}(A)$.

Until now, the proof is non-constructive. Now, what it the element $f$ you are looking for? It all lies in the claim that since $A$ is Noetherian, $\mathop{Ass}(R) \neq \emptyset$.

To show this, consider the set of ideals $X = \{ \mathop{Ann}(f) \mid f \in R \}$. Since $A$ is Noetherian, $X$ has a maximal element, and it is not difficult to show that such maximal element has to be prime. Indeed let $I \in X$ be maximal, say $I = \mathop{Ann}(f)$, and let $ab \in I$. Then $abf = 0$, and either $bf = 0$, in which case $b \in I$, or $a \in \mathop{Ann}(bf) \supset I$. By maximality, $\mathop{Ann}(bf) = I$, so $a \in I$.

In conclusion your desired element $f$ is defined by the condition that $\mathop{Ann}(f)$ is maximal in $X$. I leave to you the choice whether this is or not more constructive than the proofs you have seen. In any case the very Noetherian condition guarantees a non-constructive existence of a maximal ideal, so it is entirely possible thatone cannot get anything more explicit than this.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put into this answer, but I'm still hoping for something a bit more explicit.

Comment: Don't worry, not a big effort :-) But as I said, the fact that this is true only for Noetherian rings makes me think that the non-constructivity is inherent.

Comment: Maybe the proof above would look more explicit if you substitute the ascending chain condition for the maximal ideal condition. So you take $f_1 \in R$; if $\mathop{Ann}(f_1)$ is not maximal you take $f_2 \in R$ such that $\mathop{Ann}(f_2) \supset \mathop{Ann}(f_1)$ and so on, until you have to stop by the ACC. The last $f_n \in R$ that you take is your desired element.

Comment: The proof that "every module over a Noetherian ring has an associated prime" is fine (although you need to restrict $f$ to be nonzero). It's all the stuff leading up to that where I would like to see a more explicit discussion of $f$. (Part of the issue is that the proof of primary decompositions is typically wrapped up in the same "non-explicit" reasoning I discuss in the question.)

Comment: But you only need existence, which is easy and is as explicit (or not explicit) as the other step. If 0 is irreducible, you are done. Otherwise write $0 = I \cap J$. Now if both $I$ and $J$ are irreducible you stop, otherwise write $I = K \cap L$, and so on. This process will stop in a Noetherian ring, and when it stops, you have a primary decomposition on $0$. You can make it minimal by removing some components.

Comment:  Define weakly associated primes as minimal primes containing the annihilator of one element. Then, wAss(M) is contained in supp(M) and both sets have the same minimal elements. 
This part is easy.

For Noetherian rings, weakly associate primes coincide with associate primes. This generalizes the fact that Ass(M) is non-empty for M non-null, and is both more difficult and less explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p\subset A$ be a minimal prime. Consider the localisation map $\phi:A\to A_p$. The kernel $I=\mathop{Ker} \phi$ is the set of all $a\in A$ such that $af=0$ for some $f\in S=A\setminus p$. That is, $I=\cup_{f\in S}Ann(f)$. Since $A$ is Noetherian and $Ann(f)+Ann(g)\subset Ann(fg)$, we conclude that $I=Ann(s)$ for some $s\in S$. We also know that $I\subset p$ since $p$ is prime. If $I=p$, then we are done. If $I\subsetneq p$, then $pA_p$ is nilpotent since its the maximal ideal of the Artinial local ring $pA_p$ (here we use that $p$ is minimal). Assume that $(pA_p)^n=0$ and $(pA_p)^{n-1}\neq 0$. Pick a nonzero element $a/u$, $a\in p$, $u\in S$ in $(pA_p)^{n-1}$. Then $Ann(a/1) = pA_p$. I claim that $Ann(as)=p$. Indeed, if $b\in p$, then $\phi(ba)=0$, so $ba\in I=Ann(s)$ and $bas=0$. Thus, $p\subset Ann(as)$. On the other hand, if $t\in S$ is such that $ast=0$, then $a/1=0$ in $A_p$, which is not the case. Thus, $Ann(as)\subset p$.